# Cómo iterar una función en una lista de diccionarios?

Tags: python, lista, funciones, bucles, diccionarios

tengo esta función:

```
def revenue_per_employee(compania):
    index= [i for i, d in enumerate(company_list) if compania == d['nombre']]
    i=index[0]
    gpe=(company_list[i]['ganacias'])/(company_list[i]['empleados'])
    return gpe
revenue_per_employee('Walmart')
```

La cual debo iterar en una lista de diccionarios(company_list), en la que cada cada diccionario incluye la información ['nombre']['ganacias'] etc.

He intentado con el siguiente codigo:

```
for i in company_list:
    for i in i['nombre']:
        i = revenue_per_employee(i)
    print(i)
```

Pero claramente no me funciona, alguien me podría dar alguna claridad? Gracias

Comment: Gracias!!! Si era eso. Tendré en cuenta lo de la variable.

Comment: Perdón, te molesto otra vez @FJSevilla, pero como haría para que también me devuelva el nombre de cada compañia?

Comment: No hay nada que perdonar, "molesta" lo que quieras para eso estamos aquí :) En cuanto a tu duda, he creado una respuesta, según entiendo te refieres a que en el print se muestre también el nombre de cada compañía junto a los ingresos. si no es así no dudes en comentar. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que sobra un ciclo realmente, si tienes una estructura de éste tipo:

```
company_list =  [
    {'nombre': 'foo_company', 'ganacias': 235711, ...},
    {'nombre': 'bar_company', 'ganacias': 13171923, ...},
    ...,
    ]
```

el primer `for` itera sobre la lista y asigna un diccionario en cada itearción a la variable `i`.

al hacer por tanto

```
for i in i['nombre']:
```

lo que haces es obtener el valor de la clave "nombre" e itere sobre ella. como es una cadena lo que haces es iterar sobre cada carácter.

Bastaría con:

```
for company in company_list:
    revenue = revenue_per_employee(company["nombre"])
    print(revenue)
```

si quieres mostrar también el nombre en el `print`:

```
for company in company_list:
    company_name = company["nombre"]
    revenue = revenue_per_employee(company_name)
    print(f"{company_name}: {revenue}")
```

Un par de consejos:

- Usas el mismo nombre para la variable asociada al primer ciclo, para la del segundo y para la salida de la función. Aparte de ser confuso, puede provocar errores en ciertas situaciones. Intenta evitar ésto.
- Te recomiendo siempre dar nombres lo más descriptivos posibles a las variables, funciones, clases, etc. No solo ayuda a que otros lean tu código, sino que a ti te resultará mucho más fácil seguir la lógica del programa y encontrar los posibles bugs. Intenta sobre todo evitar las variables con un solo carácter a no ser que sea indices o casos similares en los que queda claro que representa.